# C# OptionalField default value

Tags: c#

Keep in mind this is an Older version of .net 2.0 - 2.5 because i'm using Unity 5.6.2f1

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveManager {

    [OptionalField]
    public float version = 1.5f;
    [OptionalField]
    public string versionString = "1.5";
}
```

When using the above class to save data to a text file by using BinaryFormatter, these values will be set to defaults.
version will be 0
versionString will be ""

Is there any way to have nonexisting optional fields have default values? I have been googling this issue for a while but I haven't found any useful information.

To clarify, this issue is reproduced by Serializing SaveManager class with no fields inside of it, saving the data to a txt file. Then update the SaveManager class to include the OptionalField float version, and then trying to read the saved data, and then deserialize it back into SaveManager.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mitchstewart/eb9a7a5df2f84a44fe29f1a03e8b4e20) following this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx), but using your class. I serialize and deserialize the file and the initial value of 1.5 remains

Comment: OptionalField is only valid on 'field' declarations.

Comment: The issue is found by serializing SaveManager without anything inside of it, saving it to a txt file. Updating your SaveManager class to include the OptionalField for version, and then trying to "load" the saved data (which does not have the optionalfield)

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveManager {

    [OnDeserializing()]
    internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context) {
        version = 1.5f;
        resolutionSetting = 1;
        notificationTimer = 5 * 60;
        hideNameTagTimer = 0 * 60;
        storedLevelName = "little_transparent";
        fartVolume = 0f;
        fartToggle = true;
        nametagsCollideWithCharacters = true;
    }

    [OptionalField]
    public float version = 1.5f;
```

Fixed by using OnDeserializing() Thanks for everyone that tried to help me!